# Powershell Script to count incoming emails on a daily basis will sometimes report 0 recieved emails

Tags: windows, powershell, email, exchange-server, exchange-server-2016

I'm having an issue with the below script that will at seemingly random intervals, report that 0 emails have been received. It is being run in a Exchange 2016 environment. I've linked an image of the outputs below also. Any help with troubleshooting the below would be greatly appreciated!

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.SnapIn
.$env:ExchangeInstallPath\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1
Connect-ExchangeServer -Auto

$nl = [Environment]::NewLine

Set-Culture en-GB
Set-WinSystemLocale en-GB
Set-WinHomeLocation -GeoId 242
Set-WinUserLanguageList en-GB -force

$enGB = New-Object system.globalization.cultureinfo(“en-GB”)
$GBdateShort = Get-Date (get-date).addDays(-1) -format ($enGB.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern)
$GBdateLong = Get-Date (get-date).addDays(-1) -format ($enGB.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern)

$mailbox = "countme@test.co.uk"
$emailFrom = "email.stats@test.co.uk"
$emailTo = "recip1@test.co.uk, recip2@test.co.uk, recip3@test.co.uk"
$subject = "Daily Email Report for $mailbox for $GBdate"
$smtpServer = "TEST-EX01"

$StartDateC1 = "$GBdateShort 00:00:00"
$EndDateC1 = "$GBdateShort 05:59:59"
$StartDateC2 = "$GBdateShort 06:00:00"
$EndDateC2 = "$GBdateShort 17:59:59"
$StartDateC3 = "$GBdateShort 18:00:00"
$EndDateC3 = "$GBdateShort 23:59:59"

$receiveCount1 = Get-TransportService | Get-MessageTrackingLog -Recipients $mailbox -Start $StartDateC1 -End $EndDateC1 -EventID "Deliver" | Measure-Object
$receiveCount2 = Get-TransportService | Get-MessageTrackingLog -Recipients $mailbox -Start $StartDateC2 -End $EndDateC2 -EventID "Deliver" | Measure-Object
$receiveCount3 = Get-TransportService | Get-MessageTrackingLog -Recipients $mailbox -Start $StartDateC3 -End $EndDateC3 -EventID "Deliver" | Measure-Object
$receiveCount4 = Get-TransportService | Get-MessageTrackingLog -Recipients $mailbox -Start $StartDateC1 -End $EndDateC3 -EventID "Deliver" | Measure-Object

$receiveCount1String = $receiveCount1.count
$receiveCount2String = $receiveCount2.count
$receiveCount3String = $receiveCount3.count
$receiveCount4String = $receiveCount4.count

$body = "<font face='Consolas' color=#000000>
Mailbox statistics for: <h3><font color=#dd002a>$mailbox</font></h3><br>
Report date: <h3><font color=#dd002a>$GBdateLong ($GBdateShort)</font></h3>
----------------------------------------------------------------------<br><br>
Total no. of e-mails received <u>between <b>Midnight</b> and <b>7:00am</b></u>: <h3><font color=#dd002a>$receiveCount1String</font></h3><br>
Total no. of e-mails received <u>between <b>7:00am</b> and <b>6:00pm</b></u>: <h3><font color=#dd002a>$receiveCount2String</font></h3><br>
Total no. of e-mails received <u>between <b>6:00pm</b> and <b>Midnight</b></u>: <h3><font color=#dd002a>$receiveCount3String</font></h3><br><br><br>
Total no. of e-mails received <u><b>all day</u></b>: <h1><font color=#dd002a>$receiveCount4String</font></h1></font>
</font>"

$HTMLmail = New-Object Net.Mail.Mailmessage $emailFrom, $emailTo, $subject, $body
$HTMLmail.IsBodyHTML=$true

$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Send($HTMLmail)
```

Image illustrating output:

[image: Image illustrating output]

**- EDIT 1 -**

With some tips from Theo and some research, the script is now working! For the passers-by, the changes made can be found below:

```
$startDTcount1 = "$GBdateShort 00:00:00"
$objStartDTcount1 = [datetime]::ParseExact($startDTcount1,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss',$enGB)

$endDTcount1 = "$GBdateShort 05:59:59"
$objEndDTcount1 = [datetime]::ParseExact($endDTcount1,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss',$enGB)

$startDTcount2 = "$GBdateShort 06:00:00"
$objStartDTcount2 = [datetime]::ParseExact($startDTcount2,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss',$enGB)

$endDTcount2 = "$GBdateShort 17:59:59"
$objEndDTcount2 = [datetime]::ParseExact($endDTcount2,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss',$enGB)

$startDTcount3 = "$GBdateShort 18:00:00"
$objStartDTcount3 = [datetime]::ParseExact($startDTcount3,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss',$enGB)

$endDTcount3 = "$GBdateShort 23:59:59"
$objEndDTcount3 = [datetime]::ParseExact($endDTcount3,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss',$enGB)

$receiveCount1 = Get-TransportService | Get-MessageTrackingLog -Recipients $mailbox -Start $objStartDTcount1 -End $objEndDTcount1 -EventID "Deliver" | Measure-Object
$receiveCount2 = Get-TransportService | Get-MessageTrackingLog -Recipients $mailbox -Start $objStartDTcount2 -End $objEndDTcount2 -EventID "Deliver" | Measure-Object
$receiveCount3 = Get-TransportService | Get-MessageTrackingLog -Recipients $mailbox -Start $objStartDTcount3 -End $objEndDTcount3 -EventID "Deliver" | Measure-Object
$receiveCount4 = Get-TransportService | Get-MessageTrackingLog -Recipients $mailbox -Start $objStartDTcount1 -End $objEndDTcount3 -EventID "Deliver" | Measure-Object
```

Comment: You're sending Strings instead of DateTime objects to the `Get-MessageTrackingLog`

Comment: @Theo Indeed, that is what the MS documentation calls for is it not? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mail-flow/get-messagetrackinglog?view=exchange-ps

Comment: Nope, `[-End <DateTime>]` and `[-Start <DateTime>]`. Strange description, but Type is `[DateTime]`

Comment: If that is the issue, could that explain why it occasionally doesn't work but does work 95% of the time?

Comment: Did you try with real `[DateTime]` objects? Using string representations relies heavily on the server being able to parse the string to a valid date or not.

Comment: Tinkered around this morning and was able to get everything working properly by converting the formatted string date/time to a [datetime] object. I'll pop what I'm using in the post - thanks for the tips Theo!

Comment: Glad to have helped!